# Smarty plugins issue

Tags: php, iis, smarty

I am currently working on an IIS server with php, mysql and smarty, but I'm stuck with the following error...

> Warning:
>   include(\boswinfs02\home\users\web\b1811\ez.seonppca2008\includes\smarty\libs\plugins\modifier.capitalize.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   \boswinfs02\home\users\web\b1811\ez.seonppca2008\templates\cache\28797abee8c51cc9cd28bdc13b3f002e2a7a578a.file.header.tpl.php
>   on line 20

It's working perfectly on the local server, but its throwing an error on the live server. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Check folder / file permissions.

Comment: Does that path exist? PS: use `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: @zerkms i am not sure, how to confirm that?

Comment: @nickb what permissions?

Comment: @seoppc: open windows explorer and see?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all files in the `boswinfs02\home\users\web\b1811\ez.seonppca2008\templates\cache` folder, than make that folder writeable (777 permissions).

Comment: are you sure, it's writable issue,as there are lots of cache files already, it remove error if i replace `<?php if (!is_callable('smarty_modifier_capitalize')) include '\\boswinfs02\home\users\web\b1811\ez.seonppca2008\includes\smarty\libs\plugins\modifier.capitalize.php';
?>` with `<?php if (!is_callable('smarty_modifier_capitalize')) include '\\\\boswinfs02\\home\\users\\web\\b1811\\ez.seonppca2008/includes\smarty\libs\plugins\modifier.capitalize.php';
?>`

Comment: You can always delete Smarty cache with no problems, it will be regenerated if not present. Don't be afraid. Anyway, I din't understand if you resolved by escaping slashes.